# Windows 8: Remove Album Art from Music App

Tags: music, windows-8-preview

OK, this is a serious stretch I know. I'm asking about beta software on a beta operating system, which is pretty much impossible to Google for. Here goes.

I installed iTunes on my Windows 8 machine to do some work on a friend's phone, and we backed up his music, so I ended up with all of his music library on my computer. Windows 8 seems to have generated and cached album art (which btw is a feature I despise, since I don't listen to albums ever) and now displays those images whenever I play a song in the Metro Music app.

Some of the images are vulgar. Naked people. Seriously.

Is there any way to seek out and remove these images? They have to be stored on the hard drive somewhere. I have since removed the files themselves, there is presently only one piece of music on the whole machine. It wouldn't be a problem, except that the music app displays random album art behind every song you listen to, and so broadcasts the images to the entire coffee shop. Embarrassing!

Alternately, maybe I'm misunderstanding the app. Are the images placeholders, or do they come from the store over the internet? If I can't control them at all, I simply won't use the app.

Comment: Images can be embedded in the mp3 file tag (if they are mp3 files). Not sure if this is where they are being pulled from.

Comment: That's what I thought too, which is why I deleted all the mp3 files.

Comment: Just use an app that will work for Windows 7, it should work on 8.

Comment: Are you using WMP?  I think WMP is the same in Windows 8 CP as it is in Windows 7, IIRC.  If so, there is an setting to turn album art and metatag creation in options.  Press ALT to get the menu.

Comment: ...Actually I'm not. I'm using the Music App, which is a preview metro app. I'll update the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic downloading of art/metadata sounds almost like the notorious 'Media Streaming Metadata Sychronizer' problem in WHS 2011. [Here's how to disable it to stop any further art being downloaded.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4287.media-streaming-known-issue-and-workaround-with-windows-home-server-2011-and-windows-storage-server-2008-r2-essentials.aspx#Music_album_art_and_tags_get_overwritten)